# Missing red underlines on undefined methods in Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm using PDT 3.0 in Eclipse 3.7.0 and I'm missing red underlines under method calls, whose methods were not defined. The underlines are shown under syntax errors (e.g. missing semicolons). Hasn't this feature been implemented in PDT yet or did I miss an option?

Comment: Just installed the new version as well. From what I remember in the old version there never was such an underlining for undefined function names and I don't have yet seen this as a new feature. You *might* be looking for something that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP an undefined method is not necessarily a syntax error. One of the [magic double underscore methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) such as [`__call()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) gets called (if it's implemented) when this happens. This language feature is commonly used in PHP frameworks seeking to reduce boilerplate code; eg. getter and setter methods.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to test this, but now even syntax errors are not underlined anymore. I can write any gibberish I like, without getting an error. I guess, I've messed up the configuration. Any hints?

Comment: Ok, I've simply reinstalled a new eclipse version and got back to the first problem. I've created a simple class without any "__call" method. Still calls to undefined methods are not marked as errors.

Comment: @Senekur: They are not marked as syntax error because they are _not_ syntax errors. PHP is a dynamic language and allows this, even if there is no `__call()` method defined on the class.

Comment: Not recommended but you can also have method calls that exist only in child classes. This is also not an error and difficult for an IDE to detect with certainty.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll use the debugger then. I guess I'm still thinking a little bit to "Java". :)